# Variable initialization with itself

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, undefined-behavior

Is it safe to write such code?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = x-x;// always 0
    int y = (y)? y/y : --y/y // always 1
}
```

I know there is undefined behaviour, but isn't it in this case just a trash value? If it is, then same value minus same is always 0, and same value divided by itself (excluding 0) is always 1. It's a great deal if one doesn't want to use integer literals, isn't it? (to feint the enemy)

Comment: If you hate character literals so much, that you would go on to write code that exposes undefined behavior (even multiple times within the same statement), why not just go with named constants then?

Comment: How do you conclude that you're subtracting the same value from itself? Also, suppose that an unitialised value has to be stable, and `y` is initially zero. Why would `--y/y` be required to decrement before reading the RHS of the `/` operator?

Comment: If you really want to hinder the enemy, a more effective method is making the code as readable as possible for your own benefit, but hiring an army of lawyers to stop your enemies from using the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allow me to demonstrate the evil magic of undefined behaviour:

given:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x = x-x;// always 0
    int y = (y)? y/y : --y/y; // always 1

    cout << x << ", " << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

apple clang, compile with `-O3`:

output:

```
1439098744, 0
```

Undefined is **undefined**. The comments in the above code are *lies* which will confound future maintainers of your random number generator ;-)

Comment: How the... y became 0 as result of division? That's beyond undefined to me. That's magic. Or divided random number, and decremented it from 1 to 0 at the end of calculations?

Comment: @BlackMoses One likely (that produces the fastest and shortest code) explanation is, compiler noted that expession invokes undefined behavior, so it simply removed the entire initialization, produced no machine code for it. And then the memory (or even register) holding the variable value just happened to have those values by chance.

Comment: @hyde Well, that's possible I think

Comment: @BlackMoses This trick works because when behaviour is specified to be *undefined* in the standard, the compiler can do *anything it wants*. The set of permitted code sequences is the infinite set of all code sequences. Often if it's optimising, the compiler will prefer to do nothing, since that's just as correct as doing something.

Comment: @BlackMoses and indeed, checking the assembler output of the above program, I see a call to `operator<<` without first initialising the first argument register `ESI`.

Comment: @Richard Hodges Compilers are bastards ;) Thanks for answering, well earned.

Comment: @BlackMoses: On the contrary, compilers are loyal friends! In this case, it's the programmer who's being a bastard to the compiler.

Comment: @BlackMoses haha! "Garbage In, Garbage Out" was true in 1963. It's just as true today. :-)

Comment: @BlackMoses If compilers were bastards, on any UB they'd produce the code to try and spy on your next internet banking session, then transfer some funds for their own benefit... That'd be completely allowed by C++ standard (possibly not allowed by local laws).

Comment: @hyde Maybe that's what they do, yet we don't know it. I will have nightmares today...

Answer (score 8):

> I know there is undefined behaviour, but isn't it in this case just a trash value? If it is, then same value minus same is always 0, and same value divided by itself (excluding 0) is always 1.

No! No, no, no!

The "trash value" is an "indeterminate value".

Subtracting an indeterminate value from itself does not yield zero: it causes your program to have *undefined behaviour* (`[C++14: 8.5/12]`).

You cannot rely on the normal rules of arithmetic to "cancel out" undefined behaviour.

[Your program could travel back in time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/) and spoil *Game of Thrones*/*The Force Awakens*/*Supergirl* for everyone. Please don't do this!

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior is undefined. Always. Stuff may work or break more or less reliably on certain platforms, but in general, you can not rely on this program not crashing or any variable having a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. There's no "isn't it in this case something specific" (unless you are actually talking about result of a completed compilation, and looking at the generated machine code, but that is no longer C++). Compiler is allowed to do whatever it pleases.